# Selenium: not able to loop through sub-tables on page, am I in the right frame?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm trying to scrape all the data in the food-disease section of [this](http://147.8.185.62/services/NutriChem-2.0/) database. The following script:

1. goes to the home page
2. types 22663 into the 'search by plant-based food' box
3. clicks 'food-disease associations' in the 'select type of interaction'
4. clicks submit at the bottom of the page.
5. Then on the next page, it clicks Plant-Disease associations.

There are two more steps to get the data that I want, step 6 I am stuck on, and then step 7 is 99% complete.

For step 6, I want to loop through each row in this table, click the arrow button to produce a grey box as in the image below, and extract the info in each grey box. I've attached the code, and the two specific parts that I'm stuck on.

[image]

The code:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import csv
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import csv
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

#binary = FirefoxBinary('/Users/kela/Desktop/scripts/scraping/geckodriver')
url = 'http://147.8.185.62/services/NutriChem-2.0/'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/Users/kela/Desktop/scripts/scraping/geckodriver')
driver.get(url)

#input the tax ID
element = driver.find_element_by_id("input_food_name")
element.send_keys("22663")

#click food-disease association
element = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[name=food_search_section]'))
element.select_by_value('food_disease')

#click submit and click plant-disease associations
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[value="Submit"]').click()
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('frame'))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[onclick*="plant-disease"]').click()

#the bit that I'm missing, how do i loop through each grey box on this page ##
# this next part would generally work once I had access to the grey boxes, except for not telling me if association is up or down
#scrape the resulting page:
#sample url
#url = 'http://147.8.185.62/services/NutriChem-1.0/cgi-bin/ListWrapper.php?file=nutrichem23820_disease.tsv&mode=pla$
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,features="html.parser")
table = soup.find("table", {"class":"Level2Table"} )

for row in table.findAll('tr'):
        food_source = row.find_all('td')[1].text
        pmid = row.find_all('td')[0].text
        disease = row.find_all('td')[3].text
        print(food_source + '\t' + pmid + '\t' + disease) ## how do I pull out the up or down (or the up or down.png; just something that says whether the association is positive or negative).
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to loop through level 1 table , try this approach,

```
rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='Level1Table']/tbody/tr[contains(@name,'hList')]/td/img[contains(@id,'imgList')]")

for item in rows:
    item.click()
    #scrape data from level2 table
```

In order to find association is postive or negative, you can scrape data from img tag attribute src. ( If it contains up arrow, then positive & down arrow means negative.